# sudo - ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I am running a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. Today I have been doing some maintenance to the server, and a security audit.

I realized that sudo is not working the way I expected it to. In the default sudoers file (visudo) it says that members of the group admin is able to gain root privileges and members of the group sudo is able to sudo.

My own user is only member of my users default group, but is still able to both sudo and use su.

What an I missing?

This is my sudoers file:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you aren't in the `sudo` or `admin` group? Maybe there is something in `/etc/sudoers.d`?

Comment: username@host:~$ id username
uid=1003(username) gid=1003(username) groups=1003(username)

Comment: ll /etc/sudoers.d
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 10  2014 ./
drwxr-xr-x 107 root root 4096 Dec 19 16:17 ../
-r--r-----   1 root root  753 Feb 27  2013 README

Comment: Is there anything in the /etc/sudoers.d/ directory?

Comment: Which `sudo` is being invoked? I've ran into issues before where someone installed a newer version from source and it was using the one installed in `/usr/local` which uses a different `sudoers` file.

Comment: You can find out by doing a `which sudo` as the user you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, for some mysterious reason, restarting openssh made the trick....

Comment: Had you maybe just removed the user you were testing with from the `sudo` or `admin` group? Group membership changes are applied when you log in, they have no effect on already-started sessions.